# x-if inside template elements not detecting value change. (Alpine.js)

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

When I define "dCircles" as true, the elements appear, but when I define it as false it doesn't detect the value change made in handleClick. Why is it not constantly checking the value? Here's the html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>mickeyf.dev</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles/style.css">
</head>

<body x-data="{ page: 'home', 
                dCircles: false, 
                handleClick: (currentPage) => { 
                                $data.page = currentPage;
                                if($data.page === 'dancing-circles') {
                                    $data.dCircles = true;
                                } else {
                                    $data.dCircles = false;
                                }
                                console.log($data.dCircles);
                                updateScripts($data.page); 
                                } 
                }" x-init="updateScripts(page); $watch('page', value => updateScripts(value));">

  <audio id="music"></audio>
  <!-- Navigation bar -->
  <div id="central">
    <div id="header">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="/" @click="handleClick('home')">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/dancing-circles" @click="handleClick('dancing-circles')">Anim</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/user/create" @click="handleClick('register')">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/login" @click="handleClick('login')">Log in</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Content from Dancing Circles Page -->
    <template x-if="dCircles">
            <h1 id="page-title">Dancing Circles</h1>
        </template>
    <template x-if="dCircles">
            <canvas id="dancing-circles"></canvas>
        </template>
    <template x-if="dCircles">
            <label id="upload-button" for="file-upload">Upload Music</label>
        </template>
    <template x-if="dCircles">
            <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="file-upload" accept="audio/*" />
        </template>

    <!-- Content from pages handled with index.js -->
    <div id="content" x-show="!dCircles"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Dynamic scripts -->
  <script>
    function updateScripts(currentPage) {
      // console.log(currentPage);

      // Remove existing script if any
      const existingScript = document.getElementById("dynamic-script");
      if (existingScript) {
        existingScript.remove();
      }

      // Create new script element
      let myCoolCode = document.createElement("script");
      myCoolCode.id = "dynamic-script";

      switch (currentPage) {
        case "dancing-circles":
          myCoolCode.setAttribute("src", "dist/circleAnim.js");
          break;
        default:
          myCoolCode.setAttribute("src", "dist/index.js");
          break;
      }

      // Append the new script to the body
      document.body.appendChild(myCoolCode);
    }
    updateScripts();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

What's interesting is that when I update dCircles directly on "@click", it works perfectly:

```html
<div id="header">
   <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="/" @click="handleClick('home'); dCircles = false;">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#/dancing-circles" @click="handleClick('dancing-circles'); dCircles = true;">Anim</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#/user/create" @click="handleClick('register'); dCircles = false;">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#/login" @click="handleClick('login'); dCircles = false;">Log in</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This also works fine:

```html
<body x-data="{ page: 'home' }" x-init="updateScripts(page); $watch('page', value => updateScripts(value));">

  <audio id="music"></audio>
  <!-- Navigation bar -->
  <div id="central">
    <div id="header">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="/" @click="page='home'">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/dancing-circles" @click="page='dancing-circles'">Anim</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/user/create" @click="page='register'">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/login" @click="page='login'">Log in</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Content from Dancing Circles Page -->
    <template x-if="(page === 'dancing-circles')">
            <h1 id="page-title">Dancing Circles</h1>
        </template>
    <template x-if="(page === 'dancing-circles')">
            <canvas id="dancing-circles"></canvas>
        </template>
    <template x-if="(page === 'dancing-circles')">
            <label id="upload-button" for="file-upload">Upload Music</label>
        </template>
    <template x-if="(page === 'dancing-circles')">
            <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="file-upload" accept="audio/*" />
        </template>

    <!-- Content from pages handled with index.js -->
    <div id="content" x-show="(page !== 'dancing-circles')"></div>
  </div>

  I added this to make it cleaner:

  <template x-if="(page === 'dancing-circles')">
         <div id="d-circles-content">
               <h1 id="page-title">Dancing Circles</h1>
               <canvas id="dancing-circles"></canvas>
               <label id="upload-button" for="file-upload">Upload Music</label>
               <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="file-upload" accept="audio/*" />
        </div>
    </template>
</body>
```

I still don't know why it wouldn't work with that method though, would be nice to be able to do multiple things in that method and have it work 100%.

Expected x-if to detect value change in dCirlces variable when it changes inside a function.

Comment: Is your `console.log` showing stable results? Anyways, in your next trials, to minimize factors, temporarily eliminate the `<template x-if>`'s and replace with just output value `dCircles`. This does seem silly, however I'm not surprised with the AlpineJS wrestling (personally I'm glad to not use Alpine =P).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).